# Ubuntu Live USB stick not saving to hard drive

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb

I recently made a USB live stick with Ubuntu, to replace the windows 10 that was on a older model Lenovo. It appeared to be working, but for whatever reason the USB isn't actually doing anything to the hard drive of the computer. Every time I pull the USB out of the computer, the machine returns an error and shuts down. I have gone through the install Ubuntu process probably 10+ times, changing various BIOS settings, as well as some of the install settings, but again and again it does not work. Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: after you plug in the USB live stick, did you select the **Install Ubuntu on the desktop** option which can be found at the **Desktop**? You may refer to the step below: [Install Ubuntu Desktop](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#4) or (Just ignore the dual boot part) [install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) Can you provide further details on the error as well?

Comment: It gives me a try ubuntu without installing option, as well as an install ubuntu (I have been into both of these, but have done the install many times) It also has OEM install and check disc for defects (I have checked for defects, so that is covered)

Comment: Are you getting the grub boot menu when trying to boot without the USB stick. Are you able to start the computer without the flashdrive plugged in? If not you may have put the bootloader in the wrong place.

Comment: I can start the computer without it, but that gives an error and shuts the whole computer down. Where should the bootloader be placed?

Comment: @mcnordstrom1 Place the boot loader on the root of the target drive, ie sdx not sdx1.  PS if you start your comment with @*Username* the user will be notified of your comment.